# Как считывать папку?

Tags: java

Ребят, как сделать чтобы пользователи указывали путь к папке и потом выводилось все содержимое папки?

Comment: Пишите, пожалуйста, конкретнее. Куда пользователи должны писать? Что должно выводиться? Куда должно выводиться?

Comment: @rishat, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Ознакомьтесь с классом `java.io.File`.

Обратите особое внимание на его методы `list()` и `listFiles()`.